# restrict the ElementTreeSelectionDialog

Tags: java, swt, jface

I wanna to implement `Workspace Browse`. I write the below code.

```
ElementTreeSelectionDialog dialog = new ElementTreeSelectionDialog(
            Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(),
            new WorkbenchLabelProvider(),
            new BaseWorkbenchContentProvider());

dialog.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot());
dialog.open();
```

How can I change the code to only root elements (projects or folders) that contains ".ecore" file shown? And when the user collapse any root elements only `.ecore` files shown?

Comment: You should create a new question each time you have a question, not completely change old questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a viewer filter to the dialog to restrict what is shown.

```
dialog.addFilter(new FileExtensionFilter("ecore"));
```

adds a filter.

A file extension filter would look something like:

```
public class FileExtensionFilter extends ViewerFilter {

  private String fTargetExtension;

  public FileExtensionFilter(String targetExtension) {
    fTargetExtension = targetExtension;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parent, Object element) {
    if (element instanceof IFile) {
      return ((IFile)element).getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("." + fTargetExtension); 
    }

    if (element instanceof IProject && !((IProject)element).isOpen())
      return false;

    if (element instanceof IContainer) { // i.e. IProject, IFolder
      try {
        IResource[] resources = ((IContainer)element).members();
        for (IResource resource : resources) {
          if (select(viewer, parent, resource))
            return true;
        }
      } catch (CoreException e) {
        // Ignore
      }
    }

    return false;  
  }
}
```

This is based on `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.util.FileExtensionFilter`

For Java 16 and later the `select` method can be simplified use "instanceof type patterns":

```java
@Override
public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parent, Object element) {
  if (element instanceof IFile file) {
    return file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("." + fTargetExtension);
  }

  if (element instanceof IProject project && !project.isOpen())
    return false;

  if (element instanceof IContainer container) { // i.e. IProject, IFolder
    try {
      IResource[] resources = container.members();
      for (IResource resource : resources) {
        if (select(viewer, parent, resource))
          return true;
      }
    } catch (final CoreException e) {
      // Ignore
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```